# Force.com for interactive flow

Tags: force.com

Hi i am new to the salesforce.com.
We are migrating from siebel to salesforce. In Siebel we have task based ui which is like a series of interfaces where we can navigate to forward, backward, pause and submit the flow at the end. Do we have some thing like this functionality in force.com?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get started with Salesforce functionality is [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/). In this case, the relevant Trailhead module is [Lightning Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation), which introduces all of Salesforce's declarative, visual business process automation tools. The tool called Flow is the one that best corresponds to your question.

You'll probably also want to dig in to the [Lightning Flow Developer Center](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/lightning-flow/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flow Stage with progress indicator to create interactive screens with Next, Previous and Submit buttons.

You can check below help documents for creating interactive screens.

[Display Flow Stages By Adding a Progress Indicator to a Flow Screen](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_stages.htm)

[Show Users Progress Through a Flow with Stages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_stages.htm)

[Display Flow Stages by Wrapping a Progress Indicator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_stages_wrapper.htm)